# How to plot two DataFrame on same graph for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-analysis

I have two DataFrames (trail1 and trail2) with the following columns: Genre, City, and Number Sold. Now I want to create a bar graph of both data sets for a side by side comparison of Genre vs. total Number Sold. For each genre, I want to two bars: one representing trail 1 and the other representing trail 2.

How can I achieve this using Pandas?

I tried the following approach which did NOT work.

```
gf1 = df1.groupby(['Genre'])
gf2 = df2.groupby(['Genre']) 
gf1Plot = gf1.sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar, stacked=False)
gf2Plot = gf2.sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar, ax=gf1Plot, stacked=False)
```

I want to be able to see How trail1 data set compared to trial2 data for each of the Genre (ex: Spicy, Sweet, Sour, etc...)

I also tried using concat, but I can't figure out how to graph the concatenated DataFrame on the same graph to compare the two keys.

```
DF = pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['trail1','trail2'])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. I welcome others to post a better approach.

**Solution:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(myData1, columns=['Genre', 'City', 'Sold'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(myData2, columns=['Genre', 'City', 'Sold'])

df1['Key'] = 'trail1'
df2['Key'] = 'trail2'

DF = pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['trail1','trail2'])

DFGroup = DF.groupby(['Genre','Key'])

DFGPlot = DFGroup.sum().unstack('Key').plot(kind='bar')
```

Here is an example of the generated graph: [image]

Answer (score -1):

You're one the right track, but you want `merge` rather than `concat`. Try this:

```
DF = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Genre','City'])
DF.Groupby([['Genre','City']]).sum().unstack().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I need to groupby only Genre or City; not both. On my bar graph, I want to two bars for each genre: one bar for representing data set 1 and the other bar representing data set 2.