# Scatter plotting data from two different data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, plot

I have two different data frames in following format.

```
dfclean
Out[1]: 
      obj
0     682
1     101
2      33

dfmalicious
Out[2]: 
                obj
        0        17
        1        43
        2         8
        3         9
        4       211
```

My use-case is to plot a single scatter graph that distinctly  shows the `obj` values from both the dataframes. I am using python for this purpose. I looked at a few examples where two columns of same dataframe were used to plot the data but couldnt replicate it for my use-case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[How to plot two DataFrame on same graph for comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258134/how-to-plot-two-dataframe-on-same-graph-for-comparison)

Comment: you need to make your two dataframes into a single dataframe, then you can use the hints on plotting that you've already found. thus, your question is really about join/merging dataframe. there are already lots of questions on SO re: merging dataframes in pandas

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. I was able to concatenate the two dataframes and able to create a single plot. My next challenge is to scale down my axis. Can you help me with how I can scale my y axis to show data between 1 to 1000.

Comment: There are probably dozens of questions on SO about setting axis limits for matplotlib plots. Look through a few of them, and the matplotlib+pandas docs and tell me what you find confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To plot multiple column groups in a single axes, repeat `plot` method specifying target `ax`

**Option 1]**

```
In [2391]: ax = dfclean.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='obj',
                                           color='Red', label='G1')

In [2392]: dfmalicious.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='obj',
                                          color='Blue', label='G2', ax=ax)
Out[2392]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2284e7b8>
```

[image]

**Option 2]**

```
In [2399]: dff = dfmalicious.merge(dfclean, right_index=True, left_index=True,
                                   how='outer').reset_index()

In [2406]: dff
Out[2406]:
   index  obj_x  obj_y
0      0     17  682.0
1      1     43  101.0
2      2      8   33.0
3      3      9    NaN
4      4    211    NaN

In [2400]: ax = dff.plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='obj_x', color='Red', label='G1')

In [2401]: dff.plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='obj_y', color='Blue', label='G2', ax=ax)
Out[2401]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x11dbe1d0>
```